# Shell for loop syntax error

Tags: shell

I'm doing a `for` loop in shell as follows:

```
for i in {1..10}
  do
    if [ $ [ i % 2 ] = 1 ] then
    echo $i "is odd"
  fi
done
```

Am I doing this right?I've got a syntax error near `unexpected token 'fi'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    if [ `expr $i % 2` -eq 1 ]; then
       echo "$i is odd"
    fi
done
```

**EDIT:** Using BASH you can do:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    ((i%2)) && echo "$i is odd"
done

1 is odd
3 is odd
5 is odd
7 is odd
9 is odd
```

To perform arithmetic you need to use `expr` command in Unix shells. If you are using bash then you can make use of `(( and ))` arithmetic evaluator.

Comment: Do I need that semicolon after the condition?

Comment: If then is on same line as the condition then yes you need it otherwise not.

Comment: Nice... How about the indentations? They are just for style right?

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly now. I just moved 'then' to the line below it and the error is gone.

Comment: Also I provided a similar but smaller BASH equivalent script.

Comment: Either I'm a newbie in bash or it's just really confusing and hard to code. It's not that intuitive. It has a steep learning curve I guess.

Comment: It is not that hard but takes some practice. Some good tutorials will definitely help.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not.

```
if ((i%2==1))
then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: Good one, or even `(($i%2)` makes it.

Comment: But OP didn't mention BASH any where so not sure if `(( ))` would be supported.

Comment: @anubhava I think I'm running bash. 3.2.51(1)-release.